# class "DOMDocument" not found in a Drupal 8 site

Tags: php, drupal, centos

I've found an error on a page in my Drupal 8 site; it always show this message error when I visit it:

```
Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/vhosts/mysite/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Html.php on line 286
```

I'm using Centos 6 and I runned this commands:

```
    yum install php71w-xml
    sudo service httpd restart
```

I verified in php.ini: extensions php are enabled dom, xml, xmlreader, xmlwrite
But not worked for me.

Can you give me a solution? I'm Drupal 8, php 7.1, apache2.2

Comment: Show the code where DOMDocument is used.

Comment: Is in Drupal code. The Drupal not worked. It's shown in mysite/update.php :
Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list (see the system requirements page for more information):dom but php-dom is instaled and enabled in php

Comment: I think you are installing the wrong php-xml. Try doing `yum install php-xml` and then restart apache. This thread might help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-do-i-install-the-dom-extension-for-php7

Comment: This was happening because the local machine (dev) php version  was different from the centOS server.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu with php 7.x and fixed it doing the following.

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Once done, restart your web server

[Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-do-i-install-the-dom-extension-for-php7](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-do-i-install-the-dom-extension-for-php7)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Install XML Extension

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml //for PHP 5.6
```

and then restart the apache

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

in case using NGINX

```
nginx -s reload
```